# How to export unreal assets in a package like in unity?

Tags: unreal-4

Unity has an asset exporter that export it into a .unitypackage format. This ensure that the prefab has all the links to its child assets.

In Unreal 4, its migrate tool allow for moving of assets. However, it require that both project be on the same machine to migrate from one content folder to another content folder.

How can I export unreal assets for easy sharing in a similar way to unity?

Answer (score 2):

You can start with making sure that all the child dependencies lies in the same folder lets say "MyAsset".

In Unreal we have something called Blueprints which is equivalent to prefabs in Unity I will say.

So lets say you want to create an asset as a collectible in the game. You start with New Blueprint -> Actor and name your blueprint. Afterwards double click to launch the editor. The editor will have 3 tabs viewport, event and constructor.

In the view port tab you can preview your actor and add additional objects/praticles/effects as per your need.

Comment: But how would you move assets/blueprints between projects maintaining dependency links and possibly resolve conflicting uids?

Comment: If you have maintained the folder structure then you can simply copy paste the folder into contents directory and then launch your project in unreal editor. The UE editor is context sensitive so as long as you are copying the dependencies right it can be exported as it is to other projects by just copying the folder to the contents directory of the destination project.